# Cannot compile chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to compile the chaincode_example02 followed by this [guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/) with Option 2 (for Mac). All steps were passed except compiling the code. I have the following error:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/chaincode_example02
go build
chaincode_example02.go:30:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to prepare the fabric source as libs follow command. Make sure GOPATH had been set first.

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
git clone -b release-1.2 https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.git
```

Answer (score 5):

“Fabric” source code should be available locally in your GOPATH.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com
mkdir hyperledger
cd hyperledger
git clone http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric
```

Comment: Based on your description the "chaincode_example02" is in "$GOPATH/src/github.com/" folder. is it just a copy of "$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management02" ?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error message, your `GOPATH` environment variable is not set  correctly.

Before doing a go build on the chaincode:

1. Make sure your `GOPATH` is set up correctly

   - Follow this guide
     https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH )
   - Do `echo $GOPATH` to check the value of `GOPATH`
2. Make sure you have the fabric code in your `GOPATH`

Answer (score 0):

change the import statement to github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim and use "go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"